Incorrect display of form and its components after publishing in Windows Forms
During debugging in Visual Studio 2022, the form and components remain the right size. Also after compilation into exe the form is displayed as it should be on the device where the project was built. But running the same exe on some other machines, for example, on a virtual machine, the form and components (label, button and so on) are displayed incorrectly. I am using Windows Forms .NET 8.0. When compiling I specify this: deployment mode: platform dependent; target runtime environment: win-x64; create a separate file. I have uploaded an example of my problem here

Perhaps we need to change something in the Designer.cs file in the line AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(8F, 20F); But it only got worse.
Inserting this into the project file didn't help (I restarted Visual Studio after that)
<PropertyGroup>
    <ForceDesignerDpiUnaware>true</ForceDesignerDpiUnaware>
</PropertyGroup>

By incorrect, I mean inappropriate size of the form, components (too big or too small), and font (standard font is displayed instead of the desired one)
I create forms and components like this:
Form form = new Form();
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
form.Location = new Point(0, 0);
form.Width = 150; form.Height = 120;
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = "Example";
label.Location = new Point(0, 0);
label.AutoSize = false;
label.Height = 120; label.Width = 150;
label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
form.Controls.Add(label);
form.Show();


What DPI settings (screen text scale) are used in the "correct" and "wrong" cases?
